Non nullable type is marked by Visual Studio as nullable
Lets say I have a class with a function looking like this:
[return: NotNull]
public MyReferenceType GetNonNullableType()
{
    return new MyReferenceType ();
}

I know that the NotNull is not necessary, I just want to stress that my project has the nullable context enabled and that my function returns a Type that is NEVER null.
However, if I hover with the mouse over a variable in VS Professional like:
var myValue = GetNonNullableType();
Then "myValue" is marked as: MyReferenceType ?:
Looks like this:

Why is a ? in the end? Why isnt this recognized as "non-nullable"?

It's because you use var. Let me find the dupe...
